# to pick up lists from raw data in bash, or just to format the output list_name followed by list contents

Tags: bash, awk, sed

raw data has "pool pool_name" then followed by 0-n number of lines "member arbitrary_member_ip" Is it possible to pickup lists in bash? I tried some if conditionals until I was tired. Thanks for the help in advance.

```
     pool string_name_1
     member 172.0.0.1
     member 172.0.1.1
     pool string_name_2
     member 172.2.1.2
     member 172.0.2.2
     pool string_name_3
     member 172.2.1.3
     member 172.3.2.3
     member 172.25.25.3
     member 172.25.40.3
     pool string_name_4
     pool string_name_5
     member 5.5.50.5
```

expected result

```
     string_name_1 172.0.0.1 172.0.1.1
     string_name_2 172.2.1.2 172.0.2.2
     string_name_3 172.2.1.3 172.3.2.3 172.25.25.3 172.25.40.3
     string_name_4 
     string_name_5 5.5.50.5
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is changing the default `RS` to `pool` , so every record is now separated by `pool`. `gsub()` is used to remove the `member` string from the output.

```
awk -v RS='pool' '{$1=$1;gsub(/member/,"")}1' inputfile

string_name_1  172.0.0.1  172.0.1.1
string_name_2  172.2.1.2  172.0.2.2
string_name_3  172.2.1.3  172.3.2.3  172.25.25.3  172.25.40.3
string_name_4
string_name_5  5.5.50.5
```

Comment: Going the next step: use "member" as the field separator: `awk -F '\nmember ' -v RS='pool ' '{$1=$1; printf "%s", $0}' file`

Comment: The above assumes the lines do not actually start with spaces.

Comment: 1  here denotes True , so awk gets its go ahead to do default action. which is print. Use any non zero value in place of zero.

Comment: @JBone, the 1 is explained very thoroughly at the awk tag info page: https://stackoverflow.com/tags/awk/info

Comment: @glennjackman ..got it `Since a non-zero number is equivalent to true, then awk '1' file instructs awk to perform the default action (print) for every line.`

Answer (score 3):

With bash you could write

```
unset line
while read -r key value; do
    case $key in
        pool)   [[ $line ]] && echo "$line"; line=$value ;;
        member) line+=" $value" ;;
    esac
done < file
echo "$line"
```

Same technique in awk for the performance gain:

```
awk '
    $1 == "pool"   {if (line) print line; line = $2} 
    $1 == "member" {line = line OFS $2} 
    END {print line}
' file
```